# No update received on Ubuntu 20.04 - WSL 2 for weeks

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL 2 (Windows version 20H2 build 19042.685).
It was working fine for a while but now, when I try to `update`/`upgrade` my packages it says:

> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I find it very unlikely to have no 0 upgrade for more than **two weeks**. It's like it's not fetching anything.

`sudo apt update` gives:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:2 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease    
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Fetched 324 kB in 0s (1027 kB/s)
```

`sudo apt upgrade` gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
```

I might have changed something I wasn't supposed to when I turn the virtualization on and off for my AMD CPU while trying to overclock (Ryzen 9 5900X).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not that surprising given that last 2 weeks fall in the holiday season.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04 and it is working fine. It has not updated recently. I think the last update was before December 24. I expect updates will return some time this week. Windows Updates are on hold as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 machine and updates are working just fine. It was nothing more than a holiday delay. No issue and all is well.

The update was also one that required Admin (Sudo) credentials to run and then it needs a restart.  Restarting now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @gronostaj and @John were right, it was probably due to the holiday season. I actually got some updates later on the same day after posting this!